# Parameter set cannot be resolved

Tags: powershell, function, parameters

```
function f {
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='A', Position=0)]
    [int] $Num,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='A', Position=1)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='B', Position=0)]
    [scriptblock] $Script
  )
}

f 123 {}
f {}
```

Why can't the parameter set of the second call be resolved? It seems perfectly resolvable. At least there seems to be enough information for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add a [`DefaultParameterSetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.3#defaultparametersetname) to avoid ambiguity. On the second function call, PowerShell can't tell if you're wanting to use the parameter set `A` or `B`.

```bash
function f {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'B')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A', Position = 0)]
        [int] $Num,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A', Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'B', Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock] $Script
    )

    $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
}

f 123    # A
f 123 {} # A
f {}     # B
```

Comment: Why does `f {}` still work and the script on `position 0` is bound to the `position 1` if `DefaultParameterSetName = 'A'`? Because normally, if there weren't any parameter sets, it would give an error `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Num'`.

Comment: @Oleksa it is a pretty good question really, in theory, the engine should attempt to coerce the scriptblock into an `int` but what actually happens is that it tries to bind it to the `-Int` parameter and then skips it and binds it to the `-Script` parameter. `Trace-Command` is a great cmdlet to understand how the binder acts: `Trace-Command -e { f {} } -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost`

Comment: @Oleksa this might be a bug also, it is possible that the binder is bounding to position `0` on parameter set `B` but fails to update the value of `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` to `B`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Mandatory` to make it clear that certain parameters are mandatory for certain parametersets.

```
function f {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'A', Position = 0)]
        [int] $Num,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'A', Position = 1)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'B', Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock] $Script
    )
}

f 123 {}
f {}
```