# Powershell Parameter set cannot be resolved despite types being unique in each set?

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, overloading

Trying to create a function with a parameter set for overloading usage, originally I have had a pipeline input and desired to truncate the first parameter without specifically mentioning `-ScriptBlock` ie, `myfunction @(1,2,3) {'scriptblock'}` `@(1,2,3) | myfunction {'scriptblock'}` would both work and do the same.

However I stumbled upon this oddity:

```
function AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero {
    [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Call', Position = 0)]
        [array]$InputArray,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ScriptBlock', Position = 0)]
        [scriptblock]$ScriptBlock
    )
    # code
}
AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero @(1, 2, 3)
AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero { 'scriptblock' }
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

The help printout seem to be what I expected in usage.

```
Get-Help AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero
```

```
NAME
    AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero

SYNTAX
    AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero [[-InputArray] <array>] [<CommonParameters>]

    AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero [[-ScriptBlock] <scriptblock>] [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

Why doesn't AcceptArrayOrScriptBlockAsPositionZero work? my best guess is that for some reason script block can be cast into an array on size 1, how can this be avoided then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972150/parameter-set-cannot-be-resolved/75972206#75972206 you need to add a `DefaultParameterSetName` to solve the issue. Worth noting this only happens because a scriptblock can be coerced to array without any issues: `[array] { 'scriptblock' }` so pwsh can't tell which parameter to bound the argument, thus the need to use a `DefaultParameterSetName`

Comment: that kind of flexibility can't be accomplished by normal means, it might be possible to accomplish that using a `dynamicparam`, personally wouldn't recommend that. The robust way to do it is to use named parameters